# Using susy with libsass - wrong output

Tags: css, sass, susy, susy-sass, libsass

I'm using libsass as it's faster than ruby sass and importing susy using bower.

```
@import "../bower_components/susy/sass/susy";

$susy: (
    columns: 12,
    gutter-position: inside,
    global-box-sizing: border-box
);

#content {
    background-color: red;
    @include span(9);
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: blue;
    @include span(3);
}
```

And the output is:

```
#content {
  background-color: red;
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0.8333333333%;
  padding-right: 0.8333333333%;
}

#sidebar {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0.8333333333%;
  padding-right: 0.8333333333%;
}
```

It doesn't work properly, it breaks the page. However the ruby sass output changes only the padding to `0.83333%` and everything is right.

As you can see above the libsass padding output is way different from the ruby sass output.

What is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that it's not wrong at all, I forgot to add: `@include border-box-sizing;`

I hope it helps others.